# hapijs custom http status message

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have a requirement to set a custom HTTP Status message in hapijs application. How this could be done? My code is:

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('Hello, world!\n')
        .header('set-cookie', 'abc=123')
        .message("Hello world");
    }
});

server.start((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

When I call it via curl like this:
`curl -v http://localhost:3000/` I see a custom http header `abc=123`, but http status message still `OK` instead of expected `Hello world`. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug and there's an open [pull request](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/pull/3560) to fix it.
I can confirm that I was able to reproduce your problem with Hapi 16.5 (from master) and it works as it should after applying the pull request.

If you need it right now and can't wait for the pull request to be accepted you can follow the steps I took to test it:

```
$ rm -r node_modules/hapi
$ git clone https://github.com/hapijs/hapi.git node_modules/hapi
```

then edit `node_modules/hapi/.git/config` so the `[remote "origin"]` block look as follows:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/hapijs/hapi.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

(add the third line)

```
$ cd node_modules/hapi
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout pr/3560
// optional if you don't want a nested git repo in your project
$ rm -r .git
```

And now your custom status message should work :)

Comment: Pull request merged into master branch

Comment: I updated my project dependencies file `package.json` like this: `"hapi": "^16.5.2"`, removed `node_modules` from project folder, issued `npm i` command, so node_modules was reloaded with correct hapijs version. But I still got response: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` instead of expected `HTTP/1.1 200 Hello world`